# How to make myself more visible in traffic as an EU mainland driver in the UK?

Tags: uk, driving, automobiles, scotland, traffic

I will be moving to the UK soon, Scotland to be more precise, and will be doing so with a car. A driver-sitting-on-the-left sort of car, with licence plates from an EU country (eventually I will have to switch to UK plates). The licence plate is white with black numbers and black capital letters (so typically something like ASD-098) - visibly different from a yellow UK plate.

I have never been to a left side driving country, so I will definitely be a bit clumsy first, and drive and turn slower, just to be safe. My licence plates will signal my alien origins (at least until they get switched out to local ones) to the driver immediately behind me and the one coming towards me. I tried to google other, more visible means, but when I search for related keywords, Google Images only spouts tons of Brexit-related bumper stickers at me, which wouldn't help in my case.

**Q:** Is there some other good way to visually signal local drivers around me that hey, look here, this guy is slow and clumsy, watch out and keep your distance a bit, he's new to all this drive-on-the-left <s>madness</s> *thing*?

Some countries, for example, have standardized stickers/signs/plates for new drivers (e.g., under x years of experience), learners, cars with special tires, the handicapped, etc. I'm wondering if there's something out there for experienced drivers re-experiencing learning to drive on the <s>wrong</s> I mean the other, also completely reasonable side.

Comment: I personally wouldn't worry about it. It doesn't take all that long to get accustomed to, for most people.

Comment: Something like this might work: http://www.ebay.ie/sch/i.html?_pgn=1&LH_PrefLoc=5&_sop=12&isRefine=false&_nkw=drive%20right%20sticker

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis, nice one! Please put that into an answer so we can give you some up votes!

Comment: Nothing signifies to UK drivers that you're not a local so much as continuing to drive on the right side of the road. They would definitely think "watch out" when they see you.

Comment: If you actually look out of your windows then you're already better than about 80% of UK drivers, so I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: Do not do it! Drivers hate to drive behind "unusual" drivers and will take every opportunity to pass you on the road, potentially causing an accident. Blend in rather than sticking out.

Comment: Could be worth taking some driving lessons. Most instructors will do a 'refresher' course. There's plenty of other differences in driving in Scotland vs driving elsewhere in Europe.

Comment: @JonathanReez "will take every opportunity to pass you" We are British. We know how to queue.

Comment: You will get used to driving on the left quickly, although those multi-lane roundabouts can be confusing at first. I have to warn you though, switching to UK plates is very complicated and expensive. Sell your car in its home country if you can.

Comment: Consider switching to a "driver-sitting-on-the-right" sort of car when you intend to stay there longer. It simplifies certain things...

Comment: Is there a reason you're bringing a wrong-hand drive car rather than selling yours in your country, and buying a car with correct design for the local roads in Scotland? You would, I suspect, find it much easier. Not to mention that you won't be stuck everytime you need to use any kind of automated barrier which has the box you need to interact with on the right of the car.

Comment: @JackAidley while the OP could theoretically sell his car, he could be in the same position I was a few years ago. Bought a LHD car in our home country but two months later, life happened and ended up moving to the UK. I wasn't going to sell a rather nice car when it was (and is) perfectly safe and easy to drive it around here (England to be more precise). Granted, automated barriers are a pain, but brush up on your stretches and you're good to go.

Comment: I live in scotland and have an LHD. It's not a problem (really!) unless overtaking and there's nobody to help spot for you. some things are easier, some things are harder. Also, please search up the roads you will be regularly driving and educate yourself on accident blackspots and speed limits. There are some dangerous roads I regularly drive that see regular accidents, sometimes fatal, due to the road design, weather conditions and inexperienced drivers, often from overseas. Drive safe and please pull in to allow overtaking if you are driving significantly slower than other road users.

Comment: Oh one last thing, selling an LHD in scotland might be difficult as many consider it a disadvantage, regardless of whether that's true - so it may work out better for you to switch. But I don't consider it to be the huge problem that many others do.

Comment: agree with @robert, I accidentally did the opposite as a Brit in Norway.

Comment: Top tip, use sat nav even for small trips as it'll give you a visual of which way to go round roundabouts and junctions. It's always helped me driving on the crazy continent and their driving on the right oddity ;-) and after a few days, it's completely natural and coming home in even weirder!

Comment: Also, given its Scotland, the roads are pretty quiet by comparison to London and the South East. So a good spot to start with :-)

Comment: _"and drive and turn slower, just to be safe"_ That sounds the opposite of safe

Comment: The BIGGEST mistake I made when first time switching to the "other" side of the road was to not to pay attention to my right side mirror while switching lanes for the first time... you know the one you use in Europe for lateral parking but nothing else really ... the big bus just missed me by 5 centimeters. Remember, in UK the cars always take over on your right side on a normal road, not on your left. This is important!

Comment: If you find yourself having problems with a blind spot on your right, consider getting one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Summit-RV-16-Convex-Mirror-Small/dp/B002NPQNIS/). While the distance is somewhat skewed it'll give you some confidence (especially when overtaking).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43948/discussion-on-question-by-user3554004-how-to-make-myself-more-visible-in-traffic).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a P plate. Here's an example of some on sale. (No affiliation, this is just a major UK retailer which came to mind).

http://www.halfords.com/motoring/travel-accessories/learning-to-drive/halfords-magnetic-p-plates-x3

P plates are not mandatory and are not regulated in their use in Great Britain, but they're officially recognised as denoting a newly qualified driver, the idea being that other drivers are more wary and tolerant of slowness: effectively a way of saying "I'm new round here". There are no restrictions on either using or removing them.

While the intention is that they are for "new drivers", no one would think it inappropriate (and certainly not illegal) to use them if you are otherwise unsure on the road, and to similar effect. The corollary to this is that they, of course, offer no formal, legal protection in the event of an accident.

Though it would be a nice thing to do, I'd not really worry, though.

It's easier than most people imagine to become accustomed to other-side driving and most drivers are quite tolerant, particularly outside South-East England, and those who are not tend to be equally intolerant of those acting reasonably and unreasonably, based on whether it interferes with their immediate plans.

Intolerant drivers in Great Britain also tend to voluntarily self-differentiate by car colour and brand (I won't go into details here to avoid endless name-calling), but after a few weeks you will know which cars are best given a wide berth for a quiet life, but also their protests best ignored.

**Edit:** As mentioned in comments, the situation is different in Northern Ireland.

Comment: This is a good answer. For completeness sake I would just add that "P" plates being unregulated is not true worldwide, so if you are thinking of applying this advice in other countries check the local rules first.

Comment: While P plates are okay in Great Britain (that is England, Wales and Scotland), in Northern Ireland, by law all new drivers have to use R plates. While afaik there is nothing against the law of using P plates there, it might be weird using it. On the other hand do not use R plates there, as they have strict restictions imposed.

Comment: +1 "Intolerant drivers in Great Britain also tend to voluntarily self-differentiate by car colour and brand" Someone has been watching too much Top Gear..

Comment: @Aron, I think this has less to do with people with enough money to own stuff shown on *Top Gear* than with those with just enough to buy a loud exhaust for a Fiat... Or did Dan Sheppard mean the color [white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_van_man)?

Comment: @errantlinguist He means the typical BMW driver, or possibly (more recently) Audi driver.

Comment: Ah, okay: Didn't know the reputation was (still?) that bad... I'd thought that Audis were more associated with boring upper-middle-class folk?

Comment: @errantlinguist Certainly is bad. From a statistical point of view I'm always amazed by the large majority seem to confirm the stereotypes. It makes me wonder if rather than the brand affecting the driver, it is the type of driver who tends to fall under the stereotype that is drawn to the brand through its aggressive marketing & car styling. Either that of its a confirmation bias, but i have been actively trying to take a fair view.

Comment: My view is that P plates are a bad idea.  Not just for this driver, but for all new drivers.
Considerate drivers will be considerate whatever the case, but inconsiderate drivers will see the P plate and treat you as an easy mark - they are more likely to pull out without giving you enough room, or get angry at you for what they see as your lack of experience.
I get this impression from talking to 2 driving instructors and from  anecdotal evidence from friends who used them when they passed their test.

Comment: @JamesTrotter the 'style' of driver is drawn to _luxury_ brands. For these people _status = things_. They want to be winners and they have to be the fastest person on the road because it is a race! Ever seen an Audi A3 hold at 80 while Nissans are overtaking?

Comment: @JamesTrotter, from intuition I'd agree that attitude is more predictive of brand than brand is of attitude, i.e. roughly not all BMW/Audi drivers are jerks but all jerks (want to) drive BMWs/Audis. E.g. in Germany at least, everyone and their dog wants an Audi and, while a good chunk of the are jerks, not all of them are... but there are way too many Audis in Germany, so I guess the jerk brand selection effect is less noticeable?

(Actually, it seems that, when driving in Germany, my personal hatred is directed towards drivers of huge luxury tanks regardless of brand)

Comment: I'm surprised there's no restriction requiring people who are immigrating to sell their steering-wheel-on-the-left car and get a steering-wheel-on-the-right car.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor - there are substantial physical modifications one has to carry out on a LHD vehicle though if one wants to register it in the UK (I just found out I won't have to, due to the nature of my stay in the UK).

Answer (score 20):

I'm going to take issue with Dan North's accepted answer, not that it is bad, but let me put my own perspective on it.  I am a Canadian, but spent most of my life in Scotland, learned to drive there and did for nearly 30 years before returning to Canada a few months ago.  During this time I also did regular (2-3 times a year) multi-week driving stints on holidays in Europe (France, Spain, Greece), so hope to have some insight.

Driving on the opposite side **ISN'T THAT HARD** (takes me about 30 secs to re-orientate after doing it for years). **Yes the first hour or so on your first ever drive on the other side is pretty scary** (ironically I found it best to start on a big motorway where you could cruise and get your bearings,  small roads in town are much harder).

The thing for you coming from Europe is that the roads behave in a similar way - signs are similar if not identical, motorway lanes are more familiar, you'll be used to how roundabouts work etc.  I found driving in Canada much more of a shift - right turns on red, left filter signals, 4 ways stops rather than roundabouts, motorway free-for-alls with people just ignoring speed limits (fun to be doing 15 over the speed limit in the middle lane on a big highway and have 10 cars undertake you at a much higher speed), different words on some signs.

**This brings me to my issue on using a P plate**.  Drivers in Scotland are not forgiving, you can see them venting frustrations as they have to overtake learners in branded driving school cars (that can be recognised half a mile away), and the feeling I suggest would be as a P plate (even a pretend one), you are supposed to know how it all works and get on with it. New drivers I've known have discarded P plates in a few days as they felt less pressure without one.

**To me the biggest hurdle will actually be your LHD car**.  One of the cues for my brain (at least in Europe) is changing gear with the opposite hand (so not done by muscle memory). I would find driving on the "wrong" side of the road in my normal car very disorientating, especially at roundabouts, and I would hazard getting a right hand drive car would make things much easier to acclimatise.

I would additionally suggest getting the LHD car registered in the UK will be difficult. You'll need very good evidence of the age of the car to avoid getting a Q plate which will make the car much more expensive to insure and harder to sell (cars in the UK are more identified by number-plate rather than VIN, and have digits showing the age, cars of unknown or questionable age get a Q reg).  You'll need to get the UK reg to get insurance for the car in the UK, and you'll find at sale time most dealers won't touch a LHD with a 10 foot pole.

So I would just ditch the LHD car, buy a UK one (yes it will likely be older as I'm assuming you are bringing it to offset the high price of vehicles in the UK, it isn't some classic Bugatti), and a couple of good runs will bring you the confidence you need, the more you make issue of it being different (by sticking in the LHD), the longer it'll take to acclimatise.

So in summary, my answer is **Don't make yourself more visible**, you'll be better treated, and get used to driving in Scotland much better by getting a UK car and blending in.

Comment: LHD cars from other EU countries are quite commonly re-registered in the UK.  The paperwork is tedious and has annoying/pointless elements but isn't difficult *if you have the original paperwork*.  In fact when a friend was looking into it, getting the headlamps swapped out was the biggest hurdle.

Comment: Funny tidbit, you need UK insurance to get an UK plate which you require to get UK insurance.

Comment: It may be learning to drive in Essex that makes me feel that drivers in other parts of the UK seem a remarkable tolerant lot.

Comment: I don't agree about not using a P plate, but I do agree that getting a right hand drive car would be a very good move. When in Rome, act as the Romans do. When in Scotland, act as the Scottish do (except maybe Rab C. Nesbitt, don't act like him).

Comment: What’s different between left and right headlamps?

Comment: @JDługosz on a LHD car, made for a country where driving is done on the *right*, the headlamps will point to the *right* of the centre line of the car. Drive such a car on the left side of the road, and your headlamps are pointing at oncoming drivers...

Comment: Driving a LHD car on the "wrong" side of the road will be easier at first than switching to a UK car.  The comfort with your position in the car and which hand you use to shift will outweigh having the car and the road not match.  However, if moving to Scotland for more than a short period, I agree one probably should get a UK car.

Comment: @AakashM it is a problem indeed, but note that not all headlights dip. You can have a LHD (or RHD for that matter) with flat beams (point in case, the Hyundai i30 (manufactured in CZ for both markets has flat beams)).

Comment: @dan1111 I think this is wrong. Shifting with the "wrong hand" is a slight adjustment, but you adapt very quickly. In contrast, getting your road position correct is very difficult to do consistently when you are on the wrong side of the car for the side of the road you are driving on, your visibility is impaired, and you are more likely to forget which side of the road you are supposed to be on momentarily, which is much more dangerous than taking a few seconds longer to change gear.

Comment: @MJeffryes - exactly.  How many UK tourists arrive in Spain/France etc each summer and take a hire car on a villa holiday?  Trying to go round a roundabout when you are sitting on the inside of the circle (driver is normally on outside) must be very hard.

Comment: I like the way you have a problem with other drivers for undertaking you when you are sitting in the middle lane ***not overtaking anyone***. No wonder other drivers had little patience with you

Comment: @MJeffryes I'm speaking from personal experience.  The part that is hardest is not having an instinctive feel for how wide the car is to your right and left.  This is very difficult to get used to, especially on the UK's narrow roads.  On the other hand, I have driven a RHD car in Europe, and, while I was afraid of getting confused about road position, in practice this was a really easy adjustment.  Your mileage may vary (heh) but this is my experience.

Comment: "fun to be doing 15 over the speed limit in the middle lane on a big highway and have 10 cars undertake you at a much higher speed" - mind explaining why you're in the middle lane if there is space enough for 10 cars to undertake you? @jumpingcode - sorry just seen you had same ounce of frustration at this! .. And for the record, I'm Scottish - so I'll be watching out for you!

Comment: Also, be warned, although (frustratingly) rarely enforced, it is now *against the law* (as of June 2015) to 'middle-lane hog' throughout Britain.

Comment: @killercowuk - well in the example I gave you can be moving over lanes (say from faster to slower for an upcoming exit lane), and a car (or cars) will rapidly approach in your lane, and they will happily jump into the slower lane and undertake you so you need to be vigilent.  This is in Canada, and why I say it's a much bigger culture change

Comment: @jumpingcode - as per my example, I'm not talking about sitting in the lane, that'd be fair enough.  You can be moving across lanes and they will still nip in to undertake if there is any gap to do so (and I mean a couple of inches leeway).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43949/discussion-on-answer-by-the-wandering-dev-manager-how-to-make-myself-more-visibl).

Answer (score 13):

Put an [oval country bumper sticker](http://www.cafepress.co.uk/+oval-country+bumper-stickers) on your car.
[image]

Use a white one with the code of your country (which is not a secret anyway because of your license plate), not a "generic European" one with a circle of stars, because that could be confused for an anti-Brexit statement.

Comment: And as your license plate has the information, you can put the country sticker higher up, where it will be more visible.

Comment: @pnuts I was thinking at the back only. I have never seen one of these stickers at the front of a car.

Comment: Once the car has a UK registration and UK plates I believe this would actually not be allowed. I couldn't find anything about that in English, but [this (in German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalit%C3%A4tszeichen) says there are a lot of regulations about them In Germany, it's [illegal to use a wrong one](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennzeichenmissbrauch), or something that looks like one. If the foreign plate doesn't have the blue euro thing on the left with the letter, you have to have it, but with a UK car I doubt it's legal there to have a foreign one.

Comment: Also an idea, but the licence plate indeed already features (a smaller) one on the left side, and it being a sedan type car, the oval sticker could not be placed that much higher than the licence plate. And I would have to scratch it off after chaning to UK plates...

Comment: By the time the car needs to change the license plates, the driver will be so much more used to driving in the UK that the need for the sticker will be much less.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a sticker like this:

[image]

It can be found at online stores, like [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xright+hand+drive+sticker.TRS0&_nkw=right+hand+drive+sticker&_sacat=0).

Comment: @Berwyn indeed. I think I solved that issue with an edit!

Comment: @Heidel, the OP's problem is that they have a _left_-hand-drive car...

Comment: @TonyK it took me a while to notice that, i still confuse left-hand-drive with left hand driver seat.. confusing as hell..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: Left-hand-drive *does* means the driver's seat is on the left-hand side. What are you confusing? Well if you are sitting in the car and facing the front, the driver's seat will be on the left from this perspective, which is how we think of it in English speaking countries at least.

Answer (score 8):

I learned to drive in the Netherlands and then moved to the UK with a Dutch car. It took me less than a day to get into the habit of driving on British roads and whilst I did have to be more careful on lonely country roads, in the dark after a long, tiring day (when it's easy to make mistakes such as driving on the wrong side of the road for a while), I never had any incidents.

That said, I wouldn't recommend bringing a LHD car to the UK, unless you're only doing so for a limited time:

- You will be less safe driving an LHD car in the UK due to reduced
  visibility (overtaking and exiting into traffic is more difficult)
- You'll need to import your car, which is a hassle and
  expensive
- You'll need to pay more for insurance once you're on the UK
  plates
- You'll sell your car for much less than you could at home
  since local buyers won't want an LHD car unless it's a pretty
  unique/collectable one.

Getting used to driving on the other side of the road won't be the difficulty, the other issues will be in the long-term.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it. If you are in the rural parts of Scotland, motorists are used to tourists driving relatively slowly, especially away from the main roads. *Erratic* driving (e.g. tourists suddenly braking because they nearly missed a turning, and not indicating they were going to turn) is more annoying and dangerous than people who are just driving a bit slower than "average" while giving clear signs of their intentions.

In towns with speed limits and more traffic, you will very quickly learn to "keep up with the traffic flow" anyway.

Your biggest problem with a LHD drive car will be overtaking other slow moving or parked vehicles on relatively narrow roads. Just learn to keep a bit further back and drive closer to the centre line of the road, so you have a better view past them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear, though.  Safety isn't about which side of the car you sit on.

Safety is about placing safety ahead of every other priority, including road rage, ingrained habits,  testosterone displays, playing with your phone, not missing your turn (let yourself miss your turn! And recover), *everything* else.

It's about having a love-of-craft toward safety, a desire to learn, to critically examine ones own driving for opportunities to improve, maybe even reading accident reports to see where others go wrong.

Developing confidence that your driving *is* good so you aren't flustered.

Last but not least it's about putting your full attention on what you are doing.

If you have those things, you could drive backwards and you'd be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Being Dutch, I used to work and live in the UK a couple of years.
If you're a confident driver, there's nothing to worry about.
I took the ferry from IJmuiden to Newcastle, drove around a couple of months on Dutch license plates, applied for UK registration and only had to pass the MOT.
Plus was that driving on foreign license plates, I would not get any tickets for speeding ;)
You have to adapt your mirroring a bit and look over the "wrong" shoulder but you'll get used to that pretty easily.
One piece of advice, do adjust your headlights as right now they're beaming in the wrong direction.